# Polar coordinates with arc-length instead of angle

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Is it possible to define coordinates on the 2d cartesian plane with arc length and radius instead of angle and radius. For example I could have
$$
\begin{split}
s(x,y) &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 } \arctan(y/x)\\
r(x,y) &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 }
\end{split}
$$

are there any subtle points about coordinate systems that prevent this from meeting the definition of  a proper coordinate system?

Comment: Where would the point $(s,r) = (1,1)$ be, just for example? There are two points $(x,y)$ in the Cartesian plane at distance $1$ from the origin and with $\arctan(y/x)=1$. How would you know which is meant? (Also, I'm not sure why you are calling $s$ “arc length.”

Comment: $s = r \theta$ is the arclength thats why. How is the point (1,1) handled for usual polar coordinates, it would be that same treatment.

Comment: The point $(x,y)=(1,1)$ would have coordinates $(r,s) = (\sqrt2,\pi/4)$ in your system, but the point $(x,y)=(-1,-1)$ would have the same $(r,s)$ coordinates. In other words, your coordinate system would not uniquely identify points in the plane, so it doesn’t meet the requirements of a coordinate system. The problem is that $\arctan(y/x)$ does not equal $\theta$ for $\theta$ values outside the principal range of $\arctan$. While $r\theta$ is the arclength (of the counterclockwise circular origin-centered arc from the $x$-axis, $r\arctan(y/x)$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the coordinates you want actually are
\begin{split}
s(\rho,\theta) &= \rho\theta,\\
r(\rho,\theta) &= \rho,
\end{split}
where $(\rho,\theta)$ are the standard polar coordinates.
(I used $\rho$ for the polar-coordinates radius in order to be able to make sense of the expression of your radius in terms of the polar coordinates.)

As pointed out in the comments, the arc tangent function is not good for such a definition because its range is only the angles $-\frac\pi2 < \theta < \frac\pi2.$
There is no value for $\arctan(y/x)$ when $x = 0$,
and the value of $\arctan(y/x)$ duplicates the value of $\arctan(-y/-x),$
hence coordinates in the first quadrant would be duplicated in the third.

You can improve your form of the definition a little by means of
the two-parameter arc tangent function,
$\DeclareMathOperator{\atan}{atan2}\atan(y,x)$,
whose range is $(-\pi,\pi]$, so at least it covers all points of the plane uniquely:

\begin{split}
s(x,y) &= \left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right) \atan(y,x),\\
r(x,y) &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2},
\end{split}

But there is still a discontinuity along the negative $x$ axis in this definition.
For a point $(x,y)$ where $x < 0$ and $y\approx 0,$ if $y$ is positive the $s$ coordinate is approximately $\pi x,$ but if $y$ is negative the $s$ coordinate is approximately $-\pi x.$

Note that standard polar coordinates finesse the discontinuity by allowing multiple values of the polar coordinates at any given point.
For example, the point with Cartesian coordinates $(-1,0)$ has polar coordinates
$(1,\pi)$, $(1,-\pi)$, $(1,3\pi)$, $(1,-3\pi)$, $(-1,0)$, $(-1,2\pi)$, and many other choices. We don't define $\rho$ and $\theta$ as functions of $x$ and $y$, and this is what allows us to move along a differentiable path anywhere in the plane while varying $r$ and $\theta$ continuously.

However, there is another feature polar coordinates have, which is that we can define local coordinate vectors $\hat \rho$ and $\hat \theta$ which are orthogonal anywhere except at the origin.
That is, if you are anywhere except at the origin, a small change in $\rho$ (while holding $\theta$ constant) will take you in a direction perpendicular to the direction you would go with a small change in $\theta$ (while holding $\rho$ constant). Your coordinates do not have that property. (Note that this is not a fatal flaw; there are useful coordinate systems, such as oblique coordinates, that do not have orthogonal coordinate vectors.)

Comment: Ok if I were to take the upper half of the plane (which is what I want) the x<0 issue would go away. The reason I want a coordinate system like this is because I want $s$ and $r$ to have units of length. What I wanted to verify is that there are certain things that coordinate systems have to satisfy and I wanted to confirm this does not break any.

Comment: If you restrict to half of the plane you can have a continuous one-to-one mapping to Cartesian coordinates within that region. Actually even if you just deleted the origin and negative $x$ axis (or some other half line starting at the origin) you could have a continuous one-to-one mapping. But in any case you have a coordinate system.

Comment: One other thing I can't figure out. How would I show the non-orthogonality of these vectors? Intuitively one can see that the angle will change as $s$ increases. So if I wanted to plot curves in the $(s,\rho)$ domain I can't really do this using two axes at right angles can I?

Comment: Visually, the question is when you take the curves $s=a$ and $r=b$ for fixed $a$ and $b,$ what is the angle between the curves where they cross? (In Cartesian coordinates, $x=a$ and $y=b$ are equations of perpendicular lines.) More rigorously, you could express the curves in Cartesian coordinates, find the the slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$ of each curve at the intersection point, and check whether $m_1 = -1/m_2$.

Comment: But I think it's also perfectly legitimate, once you have a formula for a curve in $(s,r)$ coordinates, to plot the formula on a graph as if $s$ and $r$ were Cartesian coordinates. This is actually a transformation of the plane and would (almost surely) change the shape of the curve, but as long as you recognize this I don't see why you couldn't do it. And in the transformed graph the "$s$" and "$r$" axes would be perpendicular.

Comment: By the way, the curve $s=a$ is a hyperbolic spiral.

Comment: I have a numerical 2d function in $(x,y)$ which I using these coordinates on. This function is defined on the tangent space at each point but output is scalar. The idea is to look at which direction this function is minimum, and make curves with the resulting vector field. If I do this process on an $x,y$ grid I get some set of curves. If I do this process in the $s,\rho$ space and map the curves back I get distorted curves, more distortion where $s >> 0$. So do you think this happens because of the fact that I am making graphs on non-othogonal coordinates on a orthogonal grid?

Comment: This might be a good point at which to ask a new question (with a link back to this one). In the new question you could describe your function and the vector field you got from it with $s,r$ coordinates, and maybe show pictures of the two sets of curves showing the distortion. I suspect the answer is to use polar coordinates (with a correction) after all, but you might also get some new people to look at your problem.